# JUnit force BufferedReader to throw IOException

Tags: java, junit

I have following method

```
    public static String readPostParams(Request request, String param) {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getBodyAsStream()));
    String line;

    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains(param)) {
                //System.out.println("---> " + param + " :" + getValue(line));
                return getValue(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Ignore
    }
    return "";
}
```

I want a JUnit Unit test to force BufferedReader to throw IOException so I can cover that part also.

Comment: Send in a file that doesn't exist. `FileNotFoundException` extends `IOException`. But it should be caused by the creation of the `BufferedReader` so it should get propagated out into the unit test.

Comment: It is very bad standards to squash exceptions like that. You should rather propagate them and handle them properly.

Comment: @NicholasRobinson thank you for your comment. As you can see I want the exception from ReadLine method. If I pass not existing file then exception will throw above the try, catch block

Answer (score 1):

You should get an `IOException` if the file is "in use" So you can try this:
(I have never tested this)

In you test use

```
final RandomAccessFile lockFile = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw");
lockFile.getChannel().lock();
```

Then call your method from above and unlock the file once you are done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test this method for **IOException**, you should propagate the exception to the calling method by *removing the try catch block* and adding the throws clause to your method:

```
    public static String readPostParams(Request request, String param) throws IOException;
```

There is an attribute called as 'expected' for the @Test annotation which you can use to check for exceptions. Your test case which checks for **IOexception** from your method will look somewhat like this:

```
@Test(expected=IOException.class)
public void shouldReadPostParamsThrowIOExceptionIfInvalidRead(){
}
```